# get the different values from radio buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm expecting to get the the value of whatever radio button is clicked, say I clicked the first one, I would expect to get the value of "High" or if I decide to click the second one then I expect to get the value of "Medium" but I get back null

```js
  function boxes() {
     let body = document.querySelector("body");
     let todoLabel = document.createElement("label");
     //
     let priorityHigh = document.createElement("input");
     priorityHigh.type = "radio";
     priorityHigh.value = "High";
     priorityHigh.name = "radio";
     //
     let priorityMedium = document.createElement("input");
     priorityMedium.type = "radio";
     priorityMedium.value = "Medium";
     priorityMedium.name = "radio";
     //
     let priorityLow = document.createElement("input");
     priorityLow.type = "radio";
     priorityLow.value = "Low";
     priorityLow.name = "radio";

     todoLabel.appendChild(priorityHigh);
     todoLabel(priorityMedium);
     todoLabel.appendChild(priorityLow);
     body.appendChild(todoLabel);
   }




   function getValue() {
     let priorityInput = document.getElementsByName("input[type='radio'][name=radio]").value;

     let button = document.createElement("button");
     document.body.appendChild(button);

     button.addEventListener("click", () => {
       console.log(priorityInput);
     });
   }
```

Comment: Boxes in called and is in the DOM already btw

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns an `array` so you can't use `.value`

Comment: `getElementsByName` gets elements by their name, not by a selector.

Comment: You've not done anything to specify that what you get should be in the checked state.

Comment: I could to document.querySelector(""input[type='radio'][name=radio]:checked"); I think but that wouldnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```js
let priorityInput = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="radio"]:checked').value;
```

This should select the first checked radio button with the name "radio" and save the value in the "priorityInput" variable.

Answer (score 0):

I use the suggestion from @Dusto to find a solution for you:

The source of your trouble is placed into the function getValue(). You have to just replace and move line *1 :

```
function getValue() {
  
  //*1 also misplaced
  //  let priorityInput = 
  //  document.getElementsByName("input[type='radio'][name=radio]").value;

  let button = document.createElement("button");
  document.body.appendChild(button);

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        //moved and replaced
         let priorityInput = 
            document.querySelector('input[name="radio"]:checked').value;
        console.log(priorityInput);
  });
}
```

Additional, for a good behaviour you schould check the value `priorityInput`to null in case no selection has being made.

Also there is a small error in boxes(): The line `todoLabel(priorityMedium);` still needs `.appendChild`.

Answer (score 0):

What you request is the functionality of a form with radio buttons. So, to get the value you just get the value of the radio button list on the form -- in short: `form.priority.value`.

If it is required that the user selects one of the options you can add the attribute `required` on one of the input elements: `<input type="radio" name="priority" value="High" required>`. That stops the submit event from happening until the user has selected one of the options.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target;
  let priority = form.priority.value;
  console.log("You selected:", priority);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>High<input type="radio" name="priority" value="High"></label>
  <label>Medium<input type="radio" name="priority" value="Medium"></label>
  <label>Low<input type="radio" name="priority" value="Low"></label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```